# Json support in Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, json, database, azure, azure-sql-database

Does Azure SQL support JSON data types?. I know that SQL server 2016 has been provided JSON support.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is now available in Azure SQL Database see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-json-in-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 2):

JSON is not currently supported, but will be available soon.

Comment: Is there a time frame you are looking at for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Now, Azure SQL Database supports native JSON data type. It's in preview currently. You can refer [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753) to learn more about it.

The example below shows a table "Orders" with an order_id column of INT data type & an order_info column of JSON data type. JSON documents are inserted into the table using INSERT statement and the JSON documents are provided as a string.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Orders;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders (
    order_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    order_info JSON NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (order_info)
VALUES ('
{
    "OrderNumber": "S043659",
    "Date":"2022-05-24T08:01:00",
    "AccountNumber":"AW29825",
    "Price":59.99,
    "Quantity":1
}'), ('
{
    "OrderNumber": "S043661",
    "Date":"2022-05-20T12:20:00",
    "AccountNumber":"AW73565",
    "Price":24.99,
    "Quantity":3
}');
```

Now, the JSON functions can be used to extract properties of the JSON documents using SQL/JSON path expressions. The examples below shows how to extract the `AccountNumber` property from the JSON document:

```
SELECT o.order_id, JSON_VALUE(o.order_info, '$.AccountNumber') AS account_number FROM dbo.Orders as o;
```